TelegramBotAPI meaning of “attach://<file_attach_name>”
I need clarification for the TelegramBotAPI section about sending files : https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#inputmediaphoto
More specifically, I'm trying to use python and requests to perform a editMessageMedia
import requests
TOKEN=my_token

params = {
    'chat_id': my_chat_id,
    'message_id': my_message_id,
    'media': {
        'type': 'photo',
        'media': 'attach://<file_attach_name>'
    }
}

with open(my_photo_path,'rb') as f:
    files={"file_attach_name":f.read()}

response = requests.post(f'https://api.telegram.org/bot{TOKEN}/editMessageMedia', params=params, files=files)
print(response.json())

But all I get is:
{
 'ok': False,
 'error_code': 400,
 'description': "Bad Request: can't parse input media JSON object"
}

I have tried multiple variations before coming here.
In the end I think it comes down to me not understanding what the Telegram team means by “attach://<file_attach_name>” in the documentation

The correct code is :
import json
import requests
TOKEN=my_token

params = {
    'chat_id': my_chat_id,
    'message_id': my_message_id,
    'media': json.dumps({
        'type': 'photo',
        'media': 'attach://file_attach_name'
    })
}

with open(my_photo_path,'rb') as f:
    files={"file_attach_name":f.read()}

response = requests.post(f'https://api.telegram.org/bot{TOKEN}/editMessageMedia', params=params, files=files)
print(response.json()) 

